# Require Azure AD Login on Linux VM

Tags: azure-active-directory

I followed setup guide from MS document: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/devices/howto-vm-sign-in-azure-ad-linux

Everything works except one thing, if I do ssh from different client (Azure requires CLI for AAD login) I can still log in to the Linux servers with a local account.  The document above says:  "Use Azure deploy and audit policies to require Azure AD login for Linux VMs and flag non-approved local accounts" but I am totally getting the runaround about how to REQUIRE logins be only through AAD credentials.  I've had a support ticket open for 6 weeks and have gone through 4 different support groups with no success.

I need this for SOC2 compliance and given that Azure has documentation that their services are SOC2 compliant, I cant imagine this is not achievable.  Does anyone know how to force Linux servers to only permit ADD credentials for login?

Answer (score 0):

To force Linux servers to only permit ADD credentials for login, try the below mentioned solution to be implemented in your Azure subscription:

**Kindly deploy the below Azure policy definitions with the resource group as the scope to disallow local login for Linux VM:**

*Go to Azure portal -> Search Azure policy -> Definition -> Select the appropriate scope -> select the definition type as policy -> select the category as guest configuration -> select the below policies*

- **Linux machines should only have local accounts that are allowed**

Assign the policy to the required scope and ensure to mention/do not mention the required local accounts in Linux VM for that scope under the parameters tab.

[image]

- **Authentication to Linux machine should require SSH keys**

Assign the policy to the required scope and ensure to select the effect '***Auditifnotexists***' under the parameters tab.

[image]

**Note :**

Ensure to uncheck the option for ***'Only show parameters that need input or review'.*** So that you will be able to mention the allowed local accounts in parameters.

[image]

For more in detail, please **refer** below link:

[Built-in policy definitions for Azure Virtual Machines - Azure Virtual Machines | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/policy-reference).